# Microsoft Excel: Mark Duplicate Rows

Tags: excel

My workbook has about 400,000 rows. I'm currently using:

```
if(countif($B$2:B2,B2)>1,"X","")
```

and dragging that down a few thousand rows at a time. Then, I'm copying the selection, and pasting as values only to get rid of the formula, and only leave the X.

I would use conditional formatting to highlight the duplicates, but I don't want the first instance of the duplicate to be highlighted.

Any idea of how to get  this done faster using Excel?

Comment: data>remove duplicates?

Comment: How about use `VBA`?

Comment: I prefer not to remove duplicates, as I still need to see them. I would just like the duplicates marked. VBA is fine, but I haven't been able to come up with anything fast.

Comment: can you sort your data or does it have to be in a specific order?

Comment: Yes, I have it sorted by the column that has the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is sorted by the potential duplicates (as you indicated in your comments), then this should work:

```
 =if(B2=B1,"X","")
```

[image]

This is notionally similar to your results, only the `COUNTIF` is going to hurt you as your dataset increases in size.

You can also apply this as a custom condition in your conditional formatting, if you don't want the "X" but want the data formatted as you described.

[image]

Comment: Worked so well. Thank you